# PowerApps - collection of multiple lines from TextBox exported to SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-collection

I am looking for a solution where from multiple lines from Text-Input, I will be able to create a multiple **separate** lines in SharePoint list.

**An example would be an input of Vendor ID (in one Text-Input box)**:

598745

698745

365984

120458

**Output (on SharePoint List)**:

ID 1: 598745

ID 2: 698745

ID 3: 365984

ID 4: 120458

I saw some solution where user used Collection Table, but it requires adding individual lines separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this one below:

```
ForAll(
  Filter(
    Split(TextInput1.Text, Char(10)),
    Not IsBlank(Trim(Value))),
  Patch(
    YourSharePointList,
    Defaults(YourSharePointList),
    { Title: Trim(Value) }))
```

The [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-split) will break down the text from the text input control into multiple lines; the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup) will remove any empty rows (which may be the case for the last row, for example); the [ForAll function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-forall) will go through all of those lines and call the [Patch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-patch) to insert a new element into your SharePoint list.